# AlertDialog com ListView em FireBase

Tags: java, android

Olá sou novo em Programação Android. Estou tentando colocar um AlertDialog customizado em uma activity nesse AlertDialog quero colocar uma listView que chame itens presentes no meu banco do FireBase. Mas quando clico para abrir o AlertDialog da Erro e para. Segue o código da classe:

```
package com.cpcp.jaykl.pesquisacpcp;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class ListaProdutos extends AppCompatActivity {
private static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<BdProdutos> listProdutos = new ArrayList<BdProdutos>();
ArrayAdapter<BdProdutos> arrayAdapterProdutos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_produtos);
    inicializarFireBase();
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            chamaTela();
        }
    });

}
private void inicializarFireBase()//inicializa o fireBase
{
    if(firebaseDatabase == null)
    {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(ListaProdutos.this);
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
}

private void chamaTela()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teste_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Testando Tela");

    final ListView listViewTeste = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTeste);

    databaseReference.child("Produtos").orderByChild("nome").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                BdProdutos bdProdutos = objSnapshot.getValue(BdProdutos.class);
                listProdutos.add(bdProdutos);
                arrayAdapterProdutos = new ArrayAdapter<BdProdutos>(ListaProdutos.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listProdutos);
                listViewTeste.setAdapter(arrayAdapterProdutos);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {


        }
    });
    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Qual é o erro exibido no logcat?

Comment: achei [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762955/3681565) resposta no stackoverflow en, da uma olhada